# MySQL Transparent Column Encryption

Tags: mysql, encryption, view, triggers

I have a table 'tab', which essentially consists of two columns 'user' and 'data'. 'user' refers to some user ID at application level, 'data' to some confidential information stored by the user.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tab(
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    user VARCHAR(255),
    data BLOB
);
```

I need to encrypt each blob in the 'data' column with an individual key for the respective user, which is calculated from the user's password and stored in a temporary table while the user is logged in. To perform the encryption and decryption, I defined two stored procedures 'encData' and 'decData'.

*There's a catch, though*: the encryption scheme should be *entirely transparent* to any application running on top of the database. Names of tables and columns should not be changed i.e., SELECT statements on 'tab.data' should implicitly invoke 'decData', while INSERT and UPDATE should implicitly invoke 'encData'.

My current workaround consists of two steps:

1. rename 'tab' to 'tab_encrypted' and create a view named 'tab', which causes any SELECT statement on the column 'data' to be decrypted:

   ```
   ALTER TABLE tab RENAME TO tab_encrypted;

   CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW tab AS
       SELECT id, user, decData(data) AS data FROM tab_encrypted;
   ```

   create triggers that cause any insertions or updates on the column 'data' to be encrypted:

   ```
   CREATE TRIGGER encOnInsert BEFORE INSERT ON tab_encrypted FOR EACH ROW
       SET NEW.data = encData(NEW.data);

   CREATE TRIGGER encOnUpdate BEFORE UPDATE ON tab_encrypted FOR EACH ROW
       SET NEW.data = encData(NEW.data);
   ```

Unfortunately, the view 'tab' is neither insertable nor updateable because of the derived column, which makes it necssary to perform insertions and updates on 'tab_encrypted' instead. Does anyone know a better workaround or alternative approach?

Thanks a lot for any help,

Jan